# GitHub "Requires Authentication" error when using PyGithub

Tags: python, pygithub

I was trying to figure out how to use the PyGithub module, but I keep getting the same error:

> github.GithubException.GithubException: 401 {"message": "Requires authentication", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#get-the-authenticated-user"}

My code is pretty simple, considering I just started out:

```py
from github import Github
g = Github("Charonum","xxxxxxxx")
user = g.get_user()
print(user.name)
print(user.login)
```

The error is when it gets to `print(user.name)`.

Comment: Looking at their [docs](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#very-short-tutorial) it doesn't look like you're initializing the `Github` class correctly.  I would read through that to find more about how to properly setup.  The error is pretty clear that you don't have your auth credentials input properly

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to use my token.

Comment: @sedavidw You can add this as an answer, I'm pretty sure OP will check it for you. Am I right?

Comment: Copied to an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [their documentation](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#very-short-tutorial), it doesn't look like you're initializing the `Github` class correctly. I would read through that to find more about how to properly setup. The error is pretty clear that you don't have your authentication credentials input properly.

Example from the documentation:

```py
from github import Github

# using an access token
g = Github("access_token")

# Github Enterprise with custom hostname
g = Github(base_url="https://{hostname}/api/v3", login_or_token="access_token")
```

Comment: I am not Somalier, the API does allow username/password like GitHub(login_or_token=,passord=) according to https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github.html